# Pandas apply a function to specific rows in a column based on values in a separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, boolean

So what I have is a Pandas dataframe with two columns, one with strings and one with a boolean. What I want to do is to apply a function on the cells in the first column but only on the rows where the value is False in the second column to create a new column. I am unsure how to do this and my attempts have not worked so far, my code is:

```
df["new_name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, correction)[0] if not df["spelling"])
```

Here, `new_name` is the new column, `name` is the one with strings, and `spelling` is the boolean. The list `correction` is what will be used for the new column, and the code is meant to check if the spelling in `name` is correct according to `spelling`, and if it is not, replace it with the corresponding value in `correction`.

The code works fine without the

```
if not df["spelling"]
```

but since it is a very long dataframe it goes through every single entry even if the spelling is correct which I do not want. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I think you can do this by correcting your ternary operator:
lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, correction)[0] if not df["spelling"]) else x

Comment: I think this is on the right track but it still gives the error The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

Comment: It sounds like you only want to apply on a subset of the rows? e.g. `df["new_name"] = df.loc[~df["spelling"], "name"].apply(lambda x: ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
correction = ['Paul', 'Jean']

# One liner for Python >= 3.8 using walrus operator
# fix_spelling = lambda x: l[0] if (l := difflib.get_close_matches(x, correction)) else None

def fix_spelling(x):
    l = difflib.get_close_matches(x, correction)
    return l[0] if l else None

df.loc[~df['spelling'], 'new_name'] = \
    df.loc[~df['spelling'], 'name'].agg(fix_spelling)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    name  spelling new_name
0  Louis      True      NaN
1  Paull     False     Paul
2   Alex      True      NaN
```

**Update** you can also use `where` with a different result:

```
df['new_name'] = df['name'].where(df['spelling'], other=df['name'].agg(fix_spelling))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    name  spelling new_name
0  Louis      True    Louis
1  Paull     False     Paul
2   Alex      True     Alex
```

Comment: I've tried it and it works perfectly, thanks a lot! Much appreciated!

Comment: I much prefer the where statement, very readable

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I was not sure because the result was different from I understood.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of `apply` and `loc` on the cells in the first column only on the rows where the value is False in the second column to create a new column, this is an example based on what you've shared.

```
df["new_name"] = ""
correction = ["correction1", "correction2","correction3","correction4", 
              ...,"correctionN"]

def correct_spelling(row):
    if not row["spelling"]:
        matches = difflib.get_close_matches(row["name"], correction)
        if matches:
            return matches[0]
    return row["name"]

df.loc[df["spelling"] == False, "new_name"] = df.loc[df["spelling"] == False].apply(correct_spelling, axis=1)
```

`df.loc[df["spelling"] == False]` selects only the rows where the value is False in the "spelling" column.

Then, `apply` is used to apply the correct_spelling function to each row. If the "name" column in a row needs correction, the function returns the closest match from the "correction" list; otherwise, it returns the original value. The resulting values are then assigned to the "new_name" column using `df.loc[df["spelling"] == False, "new_name"]`

Can you try and share the feedback.

Comment: This method also works just as intended, thanks a lot for the help! Much appreciated!